# Pass a type to a function to return a closure that returns that type?

Tags: swift, types

I've been working on Exercism.io's Swift track, after refactoring my solution for the BinarySearchTree problem to smallish code, I noticed a pattern that seems like it *could* be refactored.  I think the answer is "No, you can't do that," but I figured it was worth asking.

```
typealias BinarySearchTree = BST

indirect enum BST< T: Comparable> {
    case N( T, BST, BST )
    case E

    init( _ v: T ) { self = .N( v, .E, .E ) }

    mutating func insert( _ n: T ) {
        if case .N( let v, var l, var r ) = self {
            if n <= v { l.insert( n ) } else { r.insert( n ) }
            self = .N( v, l, r )
        } else { self = .N( n, .E, .E ) }
    }

    var  data:    T?        { if case let .N( v, _, _ ) = self { return v } else { return nil } }
    var  left:    BST?      { if case let .N( _, l, _ ) = self { return l } else { return nil } }
    var  right:   BST?      { if case let .N( _, _, r ) = self { return r } else { return nil } }

    func allData() -> [ T ] { if case let .N( v, l, r ) = self { return l.allData() + [ v ] as [ T ] + r.allData() } else { return [ T ]() } }
}
```

My focus is on `var`s `data`, `left`, and `right`.  See how they're almost spitting images of each other?  Not that it *should* be done, but could it be done:  Write a function that accepts `T` or `BST` through one parameter, a tuple position through another (`Int`), and returns a function or closure that  enum decomposition and returns the captured value of passed in type?

I realize the short names and one-liner-ness of my code is far past the point of silly.  It emerged after a few iterations over this initial solution, which I think you'll agree is more readable, though the pattern is less noticeable:

```
indirect enum BinarySearchTree< T: Comparable> {
    case Node( T, BinarySearchTree, BinarySearchTree )
    case None

    init( _ value: T ) { self = .Node( value, .None, .None ) }

    mutating func insert( _ new: T ) {
        if case .Node( let value, var left, var right ) = self {
            if new <= value { left.insert( new ) }
            else { right.insert( new ) }

            self = .Node( value, left, right )
        } else { self = .Node( new, .None, .None ) }
    }

    var data: T? {
        if case let .Node( value, _, _ ) = self { return value }
        else { return nil }
    }

    func allData() -> [ T ] {
        if case let .Node( value, left, right ) = self {
            return left.allData() + [ value ] as [ T ] + right.allData()
        } else { return [ T ]() }
    }

    var left: BinarySearchTree? {
        if case let .Node( _, left, _ ) = self { return left }
        else { return nil }
    }

    var right: BinarySearchTree? {
        if case let .Node( _, _, right ) = self { return right }
        else { return nil }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can absolutely be simplified, and probably should be, with a helper function:

```
private var vlr: (T, BST, BST)? {
    switch self {
    case let .N(v, l, r): return (v,l,r)
    case .E: return nil
    }
}

var  data:  T?   { return vlr?.0 }
var  left:  BST? { return vlr?.1 }
var  right: BST? { return vlr?.2 }
```

I build these kinds of helpers on enums to turn associated data into Optionals all the time (in some cases as a public method).

This can be used in `allData`, too, which I'd probably write this way (chained `+` is notorious for creating compile problems in Swift, and can be extremely runtime inefficient due to creating intermediate copies):

```
func allData() -> [ T ] {
    if let (v, l, r) = vlr {
        var result = l.allData()
        result.append(v)
        result.append(contentsOf: r.allData())
        return result
    }
    return []
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  A case of being too close to the problem, I suppose.  I couldn't see past the types to realize I could just return them all in, and pick what I needed from, a tuple.  Thanks.  I hate seeing repeated code that can be encapsulated like you showed.  On the chained `+`s in `allData()`, I knew of the performance issue you mentioned.  I suppose it's why I needed to cast `[ value ] as [ T ]` for it to work, too.  I had a slightly less terse version that used `.append()` in one iteration until I threw that cast into the chained `+` version.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why the `as [T]` is needed for the `+`. That's a weird side-effect of all the crazy `+` overloads.